# Shortcode attributes don't appear?

Tags: shortcode

I'm working on my first shortcode, examples in Shortcode API are not suitable for starters, so I'm almost sure I'm doing it wrong!

My shortcode:

```
function hello( $atts ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
        ), $atts ) );

       return 'Hello, World!';
       return $foo;
   }

add_shortcode('hw', 'hello');
```

And I want [hw foo=HEHEHE] to output: Hello, World! HEHEHE.

But it displays only Hello, World!

How to access & echo shortcode attributes and eventually how to set the default value (I guess I've already set the default values to "something" and "something else" but I'm not sure since I have no idea how to output them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are return two times! The first return exit the function, so your shortcode outputs always "Hello World".

Correct code:

```
function hello( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'foo' => 'something',
    'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts ) );

   print_r($atts); // Remove, when you are fine with your atts! 
   return 'Hello, World: '.$atts['foo'];

}
 add_shortcode('hw', 'hello');
```

For the second question: do a `print_r($atts)` after the extracts part!

Comment: This answer is not correct, the use of extract() and $atts is inconsistent. The extract() function creates variables called $foo and $bar and these should be used in the return statement instead of $atts. Either that, or do not use extract() at all and do:

$atts = shortcode_atts(.....) 

instead

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
    function hello( $atts ) {

        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                                     'foo' => 'Default'
                                     ), $atts ) );
        return 'Hello, World! ' . $foo . '.';

    }

add_shortcode('hw', 'hello');
```

If no value for foo is passed in it sets the default value of 'Default'.

The return line returns the words 'hello world' followed by the contents of foo then a full stop.

Comment: This is the correct answer as it actually uses the output of the extract() function correctly. I.e. is uses $foo in the return statement, which was created by the call to extract().

Answer (score 1):

you shortcode function is just fine but since you return first `return 'Hello, World!';` the function ends before running  `return $foo;`
if you want you can change it a bit to see attributes :

```
function hello( $atts ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
        ), $atts ) );

       return 'Hello, World! Foo: ' . $atts['foo'] ;

   }

add_shortcode('hw', 'hello');
```